# Unable to understand the prediction algorithm in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning

I am new to machine learning , i am running  a  code which will analysis a set of data using pandas, quandl , the code is running fine and giving output also but i am unable to understand two lines of that code ,i am posting that one

```
import pandas as pd
import quandl
import math

df = quandl.get('WIKI/GOOGL')
df = df[['Adj. Open','Adj. High','Adj. Low','Adj. Close','Adj. Volume',]]
df['HL_PCT'] = (df['Adj. High'] - df['Adj. Close'])/ df['Adj. Close']*100.0
df['PCT_change'] = (df['Adj. Close']  - df['Adj. Open']) / df['Adj. Open'] * 
100.0



df = df[['Adj. Close','HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']]

forecast_col = 'Adj. Close'
#filling the NAN datas
df.fillna(-99999,inplace=True)
// this line i am unable to understand
forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.02*len(df)))
// this line i am unable to understand
df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df.head())
```

I am unable to understand what is the use of 0.1 in the ceil function and why this code is using shift function, why they have used -forecast_out?Beacause forecast_out is giving some different values.   and we have already filled the NAN positions with some data but then why we are going drop NAN?Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often in machine learning, you'll have data samples and each sample has features and labels (many api's expect this such as scikit-learn). In your case, each sample is a row of your dataframe. The value to predict is the `forecast_col`. Since you're looking at stock data, you want to predict what will happen in the future. It's meaningless to "predict" what's happening now (you can just observe it). The `forecast_out` value is some arbitrary value, in this case it's used to say how far in advance you will predict the 'Adj. Close'.

The `shift` method aligns the observations with the future value to predict. Then with this dataframe you can easily use scikit-learn to fit a model.

```
lr = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
lr.fit(df[['HL_PCT','PCT_change','Adj. Volume']], df[forecast_col])
```

This model will make predictions from the current observed values about what's going to happen `forecast_out` days from now.

Comment: thanks for the answer , but i can not understand what is the use of int(math.ceil(0.02*len(df))) and what is the use of shift(-forecast_out)? Means i  understood that the model is trying to predit some value on the basis of Adj. Close column by the column label.But why they have wrote 0.02 * len(df) ? That is am not getting.

Comment: That part doesn't make sense to me either. The predict ahead time is 2% of the size of your dataset. I've been doing machine learning for a while and have _never_ seen that. Sorry, I don't think I can give more insight without more context. Usually, it's some arbitrary number, for example I want to predict 20 days ahead.

Answer (score 2):

I was following the same tutorial and I was stuck in your same problem here is how it I figured it out :
math_ceil(): Rounds to the highest number for example:

```
  math_ceil(4.5)
```

it will round to:

```
5
```

then the code will be multiplied by:

```
(0.02*len(df))
```

len(df) is basically the size of the dataset which in this case is 3424

```
(print (len(df))
```

In other words we are keeping track of data for 3424 days, now in our case, we will be forecasting what is happening in the future, but obviously, we won't go for 3424 days timeframe but we will take a small dive into the future, in our case it will be *69 days*(2% of our total data) beyond our last data in our classifier to see what prices will it be on that period.

So to wrap this up :

```
 forecast_out = int(math.ceil(0.02*len(df)))
```

Equals 69

Now we will use the variable forcast_out to determine the label:

```
  df['label'] = df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
```

This formula means that we are shifting the column of our dataset up so what appears in our vision is the stock price after 69 days.

Here is the code with more details you can try to play around with it.

```
forecast_col ='Adj. Close'
df.fillna(-99999,inplace=True)

forecast_out=int(math.ceil(0.02*len(df)))
print ("Dataset= " + str(len(df)))
print ("Forecasting after how many days = " + str(forecast_out))
df['label']=df[forecast_col].shift(-forecast_out)
df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df.tail())
```